# I don't get hats when I log in

Tags: bug, hats

I'm not getting hats and I didn't click 'I hate hats'. What should I do? I login daily but it doesn't let me get hats!

Comment: You should probably look at the hats page: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/. Maybe also the secret hats Meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats. I don't think you get any just because you visited SE.

Comment: @Zacharee1 there was one for just visiting a site, but you have to have hats first, *and* there was one for visiting on the winter solstice, but there's not for other days, anymore, I don't think

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the hats I have, not one is for just logging in. They are for asking, answering and voting on the main site or meta. As you have never voted or edited or flagged any thing, you have not earned any hats.

Solution?

Kind of ironically, you got two hats for asking this question, ask questions on the main site too!

Comment: Fun fact: They don't have the rep to vote.  (They need to answer things)

Comment: I forgot it was 15 rep to upvote :/ Edited.

Comment: Yeah, I now got two hats!?!?